# Mongoose Virtual Populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a projects collection that stores a customer ID and a customer collection that contains that id along with a customer name.

I need to return the customer name instead of the ID for a projects API endpoint and I'm trying to use virtual populate in Mongoose for this.

I have the following schema / model configuration...

```
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "custId": String,
    "custName": String,
    "addr1": String,
    "addr2": String,
    "city": String,
    "county": String,
    "postcode": String,
    "phone": String,
    "email": String
});

customerSchema.virtual('names', {
    ref: 'customers',
    localField: 'custId',
    foreignField: 'custId'
});
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "projId": String,
    "projName": String,
    "custId": String,
    "custName": {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'customers'
    },
    "projDesc": String,
    "projAdd1": String,
    "projAdd2": String,
    "projCity": String,
    "projCounty": String,
    "projPostcode": String,
    "projLat": String,
    "projLng": String,
    "projStartDate": String,
    "projEndDate": String,
    "projStatus": String,
    "projContacts": [
        String
    ]
});

const custModel = mongoose.model("customers", customerSchema);
const projectModel = mongoose.model("projects", projectSchema);
```

And use the following query in my API endpoint code...

```
var result = await projectModel.find().populate('names').exec();
```

The API endpoint returns data but doesn't include custName.

Anyone able to help?

Thanks!

Noticed that I'd made the virtual available to the customer model so changed as follows...

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "projId": String,
    "projName": String,
    "custId": String,
    "custName": {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'customers'
    },
    "projDesc": String,
    "projAdd1": String,
    "projAdd2": String,
    "projCity": String,
    "projCounty": String,
    "projPostcode": String,
    "projLat": String,
    "projLng": String,
    "projStartDate": String,
    "projEndDate": String,
    "projStatus": String,
    "projContacts": [
        String
    ]
});

projectSchema.virtual('names', {
    ref: 'customers',
    localField: 'custId',
    foreignField: 'custId'
});

const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "custId": String,
    "custName": String,
    "addr1": String,
    "addr2": String,
    "city": String,
    "county": String,
    "postcode": String,
    "phone": String,
    "email": String
});

const custModel = mongoose.model("customers", customerSchema);
const projectModel = mongoose.model("projects", projectSchema);
```

Comment: virtual filed names will be available for "custModel" only as you've created virtual field on "customerSchema". Refrence Link: http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-virtual-populate

Comment: Thanks Alok, I noticed that after posting so amended (see update) but it's still not returning the customer name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual populate in Mongoose isn't added by default to the output. Added the following and it worked...

```
projectSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
projectSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```